# JMeter imaps not working for gmail

Tags: gmail, imap, jmeter

I can't seem to get imaps for gmail working through the JMeter Mail Reader Sampler. It times out all the time (Error 500). I'm using the following settings:

```
Protocol: imaps
Server Host: imap.gmail.com
Server Port: 993
Username: xxx@gmail.com
Password: ******
Folder: INBOX

Security Settings: Use SSL
```

I've also tried using "Use StartTLS" without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ensure you are using right port.
2. See into %JMETER_HOME%/bin/jmeter.log for possible error messages if still fails.
3. You can possibly try any other solution - via [this java code](http://www.testinggeek.com/gmail-imap-automated-testing-solution-for-emails) from [BeanShell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler), e.g..

Comment: Apologies for the late follow up on this question. The problem turned out to be a company policy where connecting to external email servers in this way was not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I had many issues and finaly I managed to get e-mails from Gmail account, but only for IMAPS protocol. For POP protocol I did not manage to do it. First off all, you must allow IMAP in your Google account.

You can see how I resolve it here: [How to check Emails from Jmeter](http://jmeter-performance-functional-testing.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-create-jmeter-script-to-check.html)